# Redmine ERPmine plug-in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

I'm trying to install the "ERPmine" plugin :

Official documentation : http://www.redmine.org/plugins/wk-time

As the documentation says , and like every plugin i'm used to do the following :

```
importing this plugin to the /redmine/plugins directory
(successfull)
running: bundle install (successfull)

Redmine 3.4.2.stable
Attachments directory writable  
Plugin assets directory writable (./public/plugin_assets)   
RMagick available (optional)    
ImageMagick convert available (optional)    

Environment:
  Redmine version                3.4.2.stable
  Ruby version                   2.3.1-p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  Rails version                  4.2.8
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Git                            2.7.4
```

when i run this commend :

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

```
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Rake::VERSION
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::MAJOR
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of MAJOR was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::MINOR
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of MINOR was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::BUILD
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of BUILD was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::OTHER
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of OTHER was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::NUMBERS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/version.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NUMBERS was here
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/linked_list.rb:110: warning: already initialized constant Rake::LinkedList::EMPTY
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/linked_list.rb:110: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/scope.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Scope::EMPTY
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/scope.rb:41: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::RUBY
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: previous definition of RUBY was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LN_SUPPORTED
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: warning: previous definition of LN_SUPPORTED was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::ARRAY_METHODS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: previous definition of ARRAY_METHODS was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::MUST_DEFINE
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: previous definition of MUST_DEFINE was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: previous definition of MUST_NOT_DEFINE was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::SPECIAL_RETURN
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: previous definition of SPECIAL_RETURN was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DELEGATING_METHODS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: previous definition of DELEGATING_METHODS was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::GLOB_PATTERN
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:86: warning: previous definition of GLOB_PATTERN was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:381: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:381: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:387: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:387: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/promise.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Promise::NOT_SET
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/promise.rb:12: warning: previous definition of NOT_SET was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:13: warning: already initialized constant Rake::CommandLineOptionError
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:13: warning: previous definition of CommandLineOptionError was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Application::DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:41: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_RAKEFILES was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:108: warning: already initialized constant Rake::EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:108: warning: previous definition of EMPTY_TASK_ARGS was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Rake::InvocationChain::EMPTY
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:55: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/early_time.rb:21: warning: already initialized constant Rake::EARLY
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/early_time.rb:21: warning: previous definition of EARLY was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/late_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::LATE
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/late_time.rb:17: warning: previous definition of LATE was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SYS_KEYS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:4: warning: previous definition of SYS_KEYS was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SYS_PATHS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:5: warning: previous definition of SYS_PATHS was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESSED_PATHS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:8: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESSED_PATHS was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESSED_PATHS_RE
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:12: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESSED_PATHS_RE was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESS_PATTERN
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:16: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESS_PATTERN was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake.rb:70: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake.rb:70: warning: previous definition of FileList was here
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake.rb:71: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake.rb:71: warning: previous definition of RakeFileUtils was here
rake aborted!
LoadError: No such file to load -- ../lib/redmine/Pagination
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
/var/www/html/redmine/plugins/redmine_wktime/lib/timelogcontroller_patch.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/html/redmine/plugins/redmine_wktime/init.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/html/redmine/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:155:in `block in load'
/var/www/html/redmine/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in `each'
/var/www/html/redmine/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in `load'
/var/www/html/redmine/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/www/html/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/html/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:179:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Same here. Do you have found a solution ?

Comment: Just to confirm, have you run `rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_wktime RAILS_ENV=production`